# How can I detect if my app is swiped from the app switcher?

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

My Android audio player app sets up a bound service while playing to ensure that it won't be killed by the system. The app uses the system media player. The service creates a notification icon in the system bar.

When I swipe the app from the recent apps list, the app disappers. BUT: the media player keeps on playing and the notification stays in the system bar.

When I select the notification or the app icon, it starts a new instance of the app, the running instance is not reachable. It can only be stopped by selecting force stop in the system settings for apps. If I don't swipe the app from the list, I allways get back to the playing instance.

If only my app could detect when it is swiped from the list, it could stop everything correctly. But onDestroy() isn't guaranteed to be called - and won't e.g. in CM12. onStop() or onPause() is not vadlid for me, because the audio should not stop when the app just is going into background.

So, how is it possible to detect when the app is swiped from the list?

This it the service. Can anything be done here?

```
public class myService extends Service {
...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    showNotification();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mNM.cancel(NOTIFICATION);
    stopForeground(true);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
...

private void showNotification() {
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Hello", 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "AppName", "Hello", pendIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    startForeground(FOREGROUNDID, notification);
    }
}
```

This is how my service is bound:

```
private static ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
          // Not used
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
          // Not used
    }
};

private static void doBindService() {
    context.bindService(
        new Intent(context, myService.class),
        mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Android cannot start multiple instances of the same application so what do you mean by “the running instance is not reachable”? I don't see the media player in the service, do you expect the _activity_ not to be destroyed?

Comment: I expect the activity, the service and the media player to be destroyed. As the media player continues and the symbol stays in the system bar, I think, only the activity will be killed by swiping, but not the service. So "running instance" was wrongly descripted indeed. The media player is handled within the activity, the service is only bound to prevent the app from being killed by the system and to show the symbol. This is a valid procedure, as I read somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it is valid procedure. But in this case, the media player controller should be in the service so that the restarted activity could connect to it and control the running playback.

Answer (score 0):

The `Service` has an [onTaskRemoved()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) method which is triggered in this scenario. You can stop the service there:

```
/**
 * This is called if the service is currently running and the user has
 * removed a task that comes from the service's application.  If you have
 * set ServiceInfo#FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK ServiceInfo.FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK}
 * then you will not receive this callback; instead, the service will simply
 * be stopped.
 *
 * @param rootIntent The original root Intent that was used to launch
 *                   the task that is being removed.
 */
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

    stopSelf();
}
```

And remember to unbind the `Service` from the `Activity` in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`. (Whatever is in line with your binding strategy.)

Comment: It sounds weird, but without making any changes it works as expected. I tried to add onTaskRemoved as you suggested, but got an @Override error. I also tried the "android:stopWithTask" switch for the service in the Manifest, which also didn't work for my 2.2 environment. Now I don't see any difference to the prior version of the code, but swiping stops the media player and the service.